# Mongodb - Get 2nd item from collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to get second latest item from Mongodb Collection, to make sure the latest alerts are displayed "alert time" is set to desc.  i got the first item using firstordefault() method, i've tried different methods to get the 2nd item, but wasn't able to

[Prev Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsYWP.png)

[Collection screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkAJn.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can get only 2 items from your query and then pick the last one

```
collection.AsQueryable().Where(i => i.TestCaseID == CaseID).OrderByDescending(i => i.AlertTime).Take(2).ToList().LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Debugger returns this exception : The method LastorDefault is not supported in the expression tree

Comment: @NikaMaisuradze in that case, before the `LastOrDefault()` convert your results into a List: `Take(2).ToList().LastOrDefault();`

This way you bring your results into memory, and then apply standard LinQ (instead of C# trying to convert your code to a database query). Try it out and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response

Skip(1).FirstorDefault() did the trick